# Two-levelled dependencies in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple build process for markdown files:

- ".md" files are compiled into ".tex" files (**md-->tex** rule),
- ".tex" files are compiled into ".pdf" files (**tex-->pdf** rule),
- and "main.pdf" is the file which at the and should be shown (**show** rule)

As make file for this I try:

```
# md-->tex rule
%.tex: %.md 
    panzer  -o $@ $<

# tex-->pdf rule
%.pdf: %.tex 
    latexmk -g $<

# show rule
run: main.pdf
    showpdf $<

.PHONY: run
```

However, once the PDF is built a change to the any of the md files in the directory does not rebuild the PDF. I guess the problem is that the final target rule **run** does not *produce anything.

How can I write this target rule in a way that it invokes the **tex-->pdf** rule and subsequently the **md-->tex** rule  two levels down?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you're building one pdf or pdf per md file. If you only buld main.pdf, then your `tex->pdf` rule is not what you wanted to do since there are many files, not only `main.tex`. You need to modify rule and specify dependencies of `main.pdf`, or have them automatically generated, as in example below:

```
all: main.pdf

main.pdf: $(patsubst %.md, %.tex, $(wildcard *.md))

#md-->tex rule
%.tex: %.md
    panzer  -o $@ $<

# tex-->pdf rule
%.pdf:
    latexmk -g $^

# show rule
run: main.pdf
    showpdf $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.tex main.pdf

.PHONY: run clean
```